# Python webscrape from company sharepoint

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, sharepoint, python-requests

I need to scrape data from my company's Sharepoint site using Python, but I am stuck at the authentication phase. I have tried using `HttpNtlmAuth` from `requests_ntlm`, `HttpNegotiateAuth` from `requests_negotiate_sspi`, `mechanize` and none worked. I am new to web scraping and I have been stuck on this issue for a few days already. I just need to get the HTML source so I can start filtering for the data I need. Please anyone give me some guidance on this issue.

Methods I've tried:

```
import requests
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth

# this is the security certificate I downloaded using chrome
cert = 'certsharepoint.cer'

response = requests.get(
    r'https://company.sharepoint.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.aspx',
    auth=HttpNegotiateAuth(),
    verify=cert)

print(response.status_code)
```

Error:

```
[X509: NO_CERTIFICATE_OR_CRL_FOUND] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:4293)
```

Another method:

```
import sharepy
s = sharepy.connect("https://company.sharepoint.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.aspx",
username="username",
password="password")
```

Error:

```
Invalid Request: AADSTS90023: Invalid STS request
```

There seems to be a problem with the certificate in the first method and researching the Invalid STS request does not bring up any solutions that work for me.

Another method:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

r = requests.get("http://ntlm_protected_site.com",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password'))
```

Error:

```
403 FORBIDDEN
```

Using requests.get with headers like so:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) ' 
                      'AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
 
auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username = username,
                     password = password)

responseObject = requests.get(url, auth = auth, headers=headers)
```

returns a 200 response, whereas using requests.get without headers would return a 403 forbidden response. The returned HTML however is of no use, because it's the HTML for this page:

[image: 200 response]

Moreover, removing the auth parameter from requests.get `responseObject = requests.get(url, headers=headers)` does not change anything, as in it still returns a 200 response with the same HTML for the "We can't sign you in" page.

Answer (score 1):

If doing this interactively, try using Selenium. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ with webdriver_manager (so you can skip having to download the web browser driver). https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/. Selenium will not only allow you to authenticate to your tenant interactively, but also makes it possible to collect dynamic content that may require interaction after loading the page: like pushing a button to reveal a table.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect to my company's sharepoint by using https://pypi.org/project/sharepy/2.0.0b1.post2/ instead of https://pypi.org/project/sharepy/

Using the current release of sharepy (1.3.0) and this code:

```
s = sharepy.connect("https://company.sharepoint.com",
username=username,  
password=password)

responseObject =  (s.get("https://company.sharepoint.com/teams/xxx/xxx/xxx.aspx"))
```

i got this error:

```
Authentication Failure: AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password
```

BUT using sharepy 2.0.0b1.post2 with the same code returns no error and **successfully authenticates** to sharepoint.